# Microsoft Outlook 2011 - using exchange account

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I had to format my mac disk. I used time machine to recover all the docs, however, I did not had the option to export the Outlook 2011 database.

When restoring the main identity with the rebuild database, my exchange account is ok and the emails in it are still "online", however the folders and subfolders created in my computer folder, in order to emptying my account (I received a lot of emails with considerable weight)does not show up anywhere. When I tried to open them by clicking in olk14_message it does allow because it says "Outlook cannot open the file because it is not associated with the default identity".

How can I recover my emails from those folders/folders that were on My Computer folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer to your Exchange Server administrator, he will restore you data. Storage of deleted e-mail messages by default 14 days Items warning quota to restore 20 GB quota and Recoverable Items set values ​​30 GB. Typically, the system administrator sets the storage of deleted items in 60-180 days. Maybe i do not understand something in your question.

Comment: Thank You...I restore the main identity from time machine from a previous backup instead the latest... then the Rebuild of the database went well and now I have all folders and subfolders (my archive) in my Computer folder.